# Find the number of solutions to the Diophantine equation $x^2+7y^2=53^3\cdot 41^2\cdot 7$

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Find $53,41,7$ as a product of primes in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$ and use it to find the number of solutions to the following Diophantine equations: (i) $x^2+7y^2=53^{400}\cdot 41\cdot 7^{600}$, (ii) $x^2+7y^2=53^3\cdot 41^2\cdot 7$. You may use that $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{-7}}{2}\right]$ is a UFD.

My answer:

Now, if $N_{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]}(a+b\sqrt{-7})=a^2+7b^2$, then the number of integer solutions is the cardinality of the set $\{\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]: N_{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]}(\alpha)=M\}$, where $M$ is either of those numbers.

In $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$, $53=(5+2\sqrt{-7})(5-2\sqrt{-7}), 7=-\sqrt{-7}^2$ and $41$ is irreducible, so they are now all factored into irreducibles. We can check that all these irreducibles are in $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{-7}}{2}\right]$, so they are also prime in that ring. (Does this mean they are they also prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$?)

Then comparing norms, if say, $\alpha=\pm (5+2\sqrt{-7})^r(5-2\sqrt{-7})^s\cdot 41^t\cdot 7^u$, then we can use a combinatorial argument to show there are a number of solutions.

However, the norm on $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{-7}}{2}\right]$ is (?) $a^2+ab+2b^2$ for $a+b\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{-7}}{2}\right)$, so I don't see how it translates.

Comment: Note that if $x + y \sqrt{-7} = a + b\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{-7}}{2}\right)$, then $x^2 + 7y^2 = a^2 + ab + 2b^2$.

Comment: The norm on both $\mathbf Z[(1 + \sqrt{-7})/2]$ and $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-7}]$ is the restriction of the complex norm. The expression $a^2 + ab + 2b^2$ only seems different because of the way you are representing the element of $\mathbf Z[(1 + \sqrt{-7})/2]$